# best practices with infinity.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, infinity.js

I am using AirBnb's infinity.js plugin to generate an infinite list in my app.

I generate the list the first time on the create of the concerned page.
But then the list has to update depending on filtering checkboxes and select buttons.
So I have to regenerate the list.
Given that the creation of my list `new infinity.ListView($el);` is whithin the function `resetModelsListView`, if I relaunch `resetModelsListView` every time I want to update the list it creates a new listview. How to manage this please ?

```
function resetModelsListView(prodata, firsttime, funfeatureOn, specificBrand, specificPro) {
 ...

 //create listview
 var $el = $('#modelsListview');
 var listView = new infinity.ListView($el);

 //add new content:
 var $newContent = $(optionsmodel); //optionsmodel is a list of <li>s
 listView.append($newContent);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't if it's good practices, but for now I am doing this :

```
function resetModelsListView(prodata, firsttime, funfeatureOn, specificBrand, specificPro) {
 ...
 //USING INFINITY.JS:

 //clear previous list
 if (typeof listView !== 'undefined') {
    listView.remove();
    listView.cleanup();
 }

 //reinit the list
 var $el = $('#modelsListview');
 listView = new infinity.ListView($el);

 //adding new content:
 var $newContent = $(optionsmodel);
 listView.append($newContent);
}
```

Comment: That's similar to what I'm doing. I'm just checking `typeof listView === 'object'` instead, and I believe that calling `remove()` also cleans up so it's redundant to use both.